# Login Loop Ubuntu 22.0.4.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, login, gdm

Ask Ubuntu community,

I would like to share my recent experience of facing a frustrating issue with Ubuntu on my computer. After a system update, I was confronted with a login loop challenge that prevented me from accessing my desktop environment. Whenever I entered my login credentials, the screen would flicker and return to the login screen again. Additionally, I noticed that my display was clearly affected, showing signs that the video driver was corrupted.

Determined to resolve this situation and restore normal functionality to my system, I searched for solutions in the Ubuntu community and found some helpful guidance. I would like to share the steps I followed to fix the problem, in the hope that it may help others who may encounter similar issues in the future.

**1 - Access to the Virtual Terminal**

- **I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F3 to access the virtual terminal (TTY3).**
- I logged in with my user credentials.

**2 - System Update**

- To address possible configuration issues related to GDM (Gnome Display Manager) and the minimal Ubuntu desktop environment, I proceeded with the reinstallation of these packages:
- Command: **sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3 ubuntu-desktop-minimal**
  **3 - Reinstallation of GDM and Ubuntu Desktop Minimal**
- Next, I reconfigured GDM to ensure that all changes made during the reinstallation were applied correctly:
- Command: **sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3**
  **4 - Reconfiguration of GDM**
- Next, I reconfigured GDM to ensure that all changes made during the reinstallation were applied correctly:
- Command: **sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3**
- Command: **sudo reboot**

**5 - Adding the Graphics Drivers PPA**

- o fix the corrupted video driver issue, I added the NVIDIA graphics drivers PPA repository to the system's repositories:
- Command: **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa**
- Command: **sudo apt-get update**

**6 - Installation of the Recommended Video Driver**

- I used the ubuntu-drivers package to automatically install the recommended video driver for my NVIDIA graphics card, ensuring better compatibility and performance:
- Command: **sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall**

**7 - System Reboot**

- Finally, after following all the above steps, I rebooted the system to apply all the changes made during the correction process:
- Command: **sudo reboot**

I am pleased to share that after executing these steps, I successfully resolved the login loop problem and fixed the corrupted video driver on my Ubuntu system. My desktop environment is now functioning perfectly, and the display seems to be back to its optimal form.

Comment: Feel free to break this up into a Q&A instead of one thing.